# How to make the PS1 character bolder?

Tags: string, user-interface

This is my current `PS1`:

```
PS1='\e[46m [\u@\A \W]\$ \e[0m '
```

It look like this:

[image]

But I’d like thefont to be in **bold** style. Is it possible?

Comment: Escape code interpretation depends on the terminal emulator, and you haven't told use which one you use (`xterm`? `gnome-terminal`? something else?)

Comment: @dirkt Sorry,how to know which I'm in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `PS1='\[\e[46;1m\] [\u@\A \W]\$ \[\e[0m\] '`

The `;1` should add the bold colour.

You want to wrap the non-printing stuff in `\[...\]` -- this allows bash to properly calculate the width of your prompt. You might find yourself in situations where the prompt acts oddly otherwise.

Comment: "Almost"? Care to elaborate?

Comment: ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

Comment: Sorry my English..